# Python generate random right skewed gaussian with constraints

Tags: python, python-3.x, probability, gaussian

I need to generate a unit curve that is going to look like a right skewed gaussian and I have the following constraints:

- The X axis is Days (variable but usually 45+)
- All values on the Y axis sum to 1
- The peak will always occur around day 4 or 5

Example:

[image: Example]

Is there a way to do this programmatically in python?

Comment: It is really looks like Gamma distribution. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.gamma.html

Comment: Entirely possible that i misspoke, I'll review your link. thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Another thing to review would be `All values on the Y axis sum to 1` requirement. It doesn't make much sense. Usually normalization requirement is integral of the function from 0 to max value is equal to 1

Comment: Agreed, I just wanted to put all the business rules i was given

Answer (score 1):

as noted by @Severin, a gamma looks to be a reasonable fit.  e.g:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sps

x = np.linspace(75)
plt.plot(x, sps.gamma.pdf(x, 4) '.-')
plt.show()
```

if they really need to sum to 1, rather than integrate, I'd use the `cdf` and then use `np.diff` on the result